# Merge two Graph entries into one - about one website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-apps

I've had like buttons on my photography website http://www.tomaskouba.cz. The main page had 15 likes and some of the pictures had likes too. About a month ago, I played with Facebook Apps, made an FB application saying it's url is www.tomaskouba.cz, set up canvas and deactivated the canvas soon.

**Problem:**

Likes disappeared. I can see in Graph API, that my 15 likes are at URL 
https://graph.facebook.com/http://www.tomaskouba.cz (btw I didn't look at my likes for 2 month so I'm not 100% sure if my app is the reason)

An when I check my FB app: https://graph.facebook.com/175067675881467 it gives some info but not domain (which I filled in the app settings) and not likes.

**Question:**

1. What URL should I give in Like Button to have 15 likes back?
2. Is it possilble to join these Graph entries to have my likes back under url www.tomaskouba.cz?

Thank you!

Comment: Works for me.  I see "15 people like this."

Comment: i can also see the likes, and looking at the page source, the url seems correct

Comment: you can see 15 likes on the bottom of http://www.tomaskouba.cz? Or when you put `http://www.tomaskouba.cz` as URL into Like button at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ ?